# Why does this sentence have "[sic]"?

Tags: word-usage

[This article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-trending-33560980) on BBC website has the sentence

> Who goes on a job interview, gets hired, and commits suicide in a jail cell after being arrested [sic] for a routine traffic stop?

As I understand *[sic]*, it's meant to imply there's an error in the original text that the reporter is stating verbatim.

Arrested is spelt correctly, so is the *[sic]* unnecessary in this instance, or does it refer to something else in the sentence?

Comment: Maybe the guy wasn't actually arrested? (Perhaps he was rather detained). Or it used to emphasize that he was arrested for a routine traffic stop. Sic is used to point out surprising assertion as well

Comment: @Sprottenwels the guy was a woman.  It is interesting to note that the BBC *has* corrected something in the original tweet, which had the letter "d" where they quote the word "for" -- immediately *after* [sic]! "Who goes on a job interview, gets hired, and commits suicide in a jail cell after being arrested d a routine traffic stop?"  I think that there was an editing error; see my answer for the explanation.

Comment: There is one obvious way to attempt to find why the BBC website used that _[sic]_. Asking here has given rise to speculation. A relevant question would be 'What are the recognised usages of _[sic]_ in quoted material?'

Comment: 'Being arrested for a routine traffic stop' makes as much sense as 'Being arrested for a passport inspection'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: You obviously haven't spent much time as a poor person in contact with American police.  People frequently ARE arrested as a result of routine traffic stops: it's happened to me three times.  (And I'm white :-))

Comment: @jamesqf You were arrested as a result of / following a routine traffic stop, not 'arrested for a routine traffic stop'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Wrong, the proximate cause of the arrest was the traffic stop.  Now I suppose that if you wanted to be pedantic, you could write something like "arrested after a traffic stop for no reason other than because the cop was an authoritarian d***head", but could you fit that in a Twitter message?

Comment: Well, in British English, the only meaning I can give to "X was arrested for a traffic stop" would be "X was arrested for impersonating a police officer and detaining somebody on the pretence of making a traffic stop". As @EdwinAshworth said, being arrested **for** a traffic stop makes no sense. Being arrested **after** a routine traffic stop does make sense, if the stop resulted in reasonable suspicion that an arrestable offence had been committed, even though the offence had nothing to do with the traffic stop itself.

Comment: @jamesq: Wrong. The ratio of hits on Google searches for "arrested after a routine traffic stop" : "arrested for a routine traffic stop", after deleting the duplicate and the one above, is 22 000 : 1. And if you read the original, you will see that the charge (and hence the arrest) was actually nothing to do with a traffic violation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, this is a depressing question.

The original tweet asks what woman commits suicide in a jail cell after getting a job and being "arrested for a routine traffic stop."   Ms. Bland was not arrested for a traffic stop, which is not really a process, nor was she arrested for a traffic violation; rather, she was arrested on the charge of assaulting a public servant, as said earlier in the article.

The [*sic*] is to reflect that the erroneous statement that Ms. Bland was "arrested for a...traffic stop" is an error of the original tweeter, and not BBC's.

Comment: +1 for enlightening us on the original. But it does seem an unusual use of [*sic*]. I think I would simply have placed *after being arrested for a routine traffic stop* in inverted commas, indicating that it was a direct quotation. People do not normally 'get arrested' for routine traffic offences.

Comment: @WS2 the BBC can't add punctuation to someone else's tweet; all they can do is add material in square brackets.

Comment: I don't think this is correct; I think it is an editing error.  See my answer.

Comment: @WS2 That whole sentence is in quotes, and the whole purpose of [sic] is to make it clear that a mistake in a quote is an error in the original, not an error of transcription. Adding further punctuation to the quote would fail to make that clear.

Comment: @WS2 Plus it is really hard to infer what someone means when they put something in extra quotes like that. Is it actually a direct quote? Are they being facetious? Is it meant to convey a mistake? Is it to add emphasis? Quotes would have added more questions that [sic] in my opinion.

Comment: @Brad Yes, I do see the point that is being made.

Comment: Isn't [*sic*] supposed to be used for errors of expression, like grammatical errors, not errors of intent, like incorrect facts?

Answer (score 46):

The original tweet was:

> Who goes on a job interview, gets hired, and commits suicide in a jail cell after being arrested d a routine traffic stop?

Note "d" where the BBC has "for."  I suspect that the reporter wrote this:

> Who goes on a job interview, gets hired, and commits suicide in a jail cell after being arrested d [sic] a routine traffic stop?

And then an editor incorrectly "corrected" it to the quote in the BBC piece:

> Who goes on a job interview, gets hired, and commits suicide in a jail cell after being arrested [sic] for a routine traffic stop?

Exal's answer suggests that [sic] indicates that the arrest was not for a traffic stop but for the more serious offense of assaulting a public servant.  However, if that were true, [sic] should appear after "for a routine traffic stop," ([sic] always *follows* the material that it marks):

> Who goes on a job interview, gets hired, and commits suicide in a jail cell after being arrested for a routine traffic stop [sic]?

Similarly, Yohann V.'s answer suggests that [sic] is marking an odd or erroneous word, but the word being marked is "arrested" -- which is certainly not erroneous or odd; it is the *reason* for the arrest that is odd, so, again, [sic] should be at the end of the quote.

Comment: Sic erat scriptum, "thus was it written", referred to the extra "d" in the tweet.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman but it wasn't an *extra* d; the d was there instead of something else, most likely "for."  If you remove the d from the tweet, you get something that is clearly missing a preposition.

Comment: I meant extra as in not the preceding "d" of "arrested".

Comment: @CeesTimmerman aha! I hadn't thought of that possibility.

Comment: The "d" may also have been intended to be "during".

Comment: @cjm I thought of that too. *During* would make sense.

Comment: Case closed, BBC editors don't pay enough attention, d = during, quote = misquote

Comment: @cjm or, if one is typing "for" on a mobile device, the word recognition might have been off.  D is adjacent to F, after all.

Comment: The trouble with _for_, as Exal points out, is that it doesn’t make sense. There is no such thing as being arrested for a routine traffic stop—traffic stops are not offenses. If anything, she would have been arrested _in_ a routine traffic stop, or indeed _during_ one. The tweet cited is 139 characters long, which is just one less than the maximum 140 allowed. It seems reasonable that _d_ would be a shorthand way of writing _during_ in this case. _For_ is certainly not an option at all, ’cause that would have made the tweet untweetable.

Comment: The correct way for the BBC editors to have handled it would of course have been to write, “…after being arrested d[uring] a routine traffic stop”.

Comment: I love the irony of the incorrect answer being the accepted answer here. Perhaps that deserves a [sic] of its own. :P

Comment: @MaskedMan it is ever so slightly less ironic if you know that the answer was accepted before this answer was posted.  To my taste, the more delicious irony is the fact that in its published form, the quotation was incorrectly marked as a correct rendering of an incorrect tweet, because it was incorrectly "corrected" (if this hypothesis is correct).

Answer (score 11):

Sic does not necessarily denote a spelling mistake. It is an abbreviation of the latin `sic erat scriptum`, roughly translatable to `thus was it written`. It is meant to indicate that the quotation was copied exactly. It is not limited to spelling mistakes and can also mean:

- Incorrect information
- Unusual word usage/spelling
- Archaic word usage/spelling

It does not necessarily even mean that there is an error. The information may be correct, but might be interpreted as an error by some. At the end of the day this indicates that any confusion stems from the source and not the writer.

Comment: Your answer is the one addressing the question in the sense most relevant to this site. (!).